# selenium find elements by css selector isnt returning all the list items

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning to use selenium and was trying to scrape the zillow website for rental listings in my city.

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_PATH)
driver.get("https://www.zillow.com/homes")
# enter search inputs(city- toronto, for rent, 
# price - $1000 - $2000)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#srp-search-box input")
while search_box.get_attribute('value') != "":
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    search_box.send_keys('Toronto, ON')
    listing_type = driver.find_element_by_id("listing-type")
    listing_type.click()
    for_rent = driver.find_element_by_id("isForRent")
    for_rent.click()
    price_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("price")
    price_btn.click()
    min_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#min-options #min-1000 button" )
    min_price.click()
    max_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#max-options #max-2000 button")
    max_price.click()
    search_box_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#srp-search-box button")
    search_box_button.click()
    # search through the grid to get all the listings
    listings_link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#grid-search-results li .list-card-info a")
    print(len(listings_link))
    for link in listings_link:
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))**
```

when I try to print the links or even check the length of the list I only get an output of 9, when in fact there are over 70 list items that fulfill the criteria that I described in `listing_link`.
I would appreciate any tips on how to get all the listings

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'd have to scroll down to each and every element on the website to let Selenium know that they are in view port.

**Code :**

```
#search through the grid to get all the listings

listings_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//article[contains(@class,'list-card ')]")
j = 0
addr = []
rent = []
for i in range(len(listings_link)):
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//article[contains(@class,'list-card ')]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements[j])
    time.sleep(.5)
    addr.append(elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::a/address").text)
    rent.append(elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::div[@class='list-card-price']").text)
    j = j  + 1

print(addr, rent)
```

**Output :**

```
['10 York St, Toronto, ON', '56 Annie Craig Dr, Toronto, ON', '219 Dundas St E, Toronto, ON', '8 Mondeo Dr, Toronto, ON', '83 Hook Ave N, Toronto, ON M6P 1T3', '70 Cambridge Ave, Toronto, ON', '1030 King St W #1036, Toronto, ON M6K 0B4', '150 Alton Towers Cir, Toronto, ON', '89 McGill St, Toronto, ON', '27 Degrey Ct #BASEMENT, Toronto, ON M1G 1N5', '11 Wellesley St W, Toronto, ON', '15 Singer Ct #603, Toronto, ON M2K 0B1', '26 Western Battery Rd #207, Toronto, ON M6K 3N9', '7 Grenville St, Toronto, ON', '5 Neston Ave #BASEMENT, Toronto, ON M1K 4M9', '142 Bob Yuill Dr, Toronto, ON M9M 0B1', '501 Adelaide St W #710, Toronto, ON M5V 0R3', '234 Sammon Ave, Toronto, ON M4J 1Z3', '33 Empress Ave, Toronto, ON', '20 Elsie Ln #124, Toronto, ON M6P 3N9', '20 Thomas Riley Rd, Toronto, ON', '39 Brant St, Toronto, ON', '4 Nicolan Rd #BASEMENT, Toronto, ON M1M 3J6', '11A Lonborough Ave, York, ON M6M 1X2', '375 King St W, Toronto, ON', '220 Redpath Ave, Toronto, ON', '1 Old Mill Dr, Toronto, ON', '3091 Dufferin St #638, Toronto, ON M6A 0C4', '458 Oakwood Ave #502, Toronto, ON M6E 2W6', '28 Byng Ave, Toronto, ON', '66 Kippendavie Ave #310, Toronto, ON M4L 0A4', '715 Lawrence Ave W #23, North York, ON M6B 2Y2', '151 Dan Leckie Way, Toronto, ON', '95 Santamonica Blvd, Toronto, ON M1L 4H3', '393 King St W #908, Toronto, ON M5V 3G8', '34 Fraserwood Ave #1, Toronto, ON M6B 2N5', '2A Church St, Toronto, ON', '33 Thistlewaite Cres, Toronto, ON M1S 3Y8', '153 Cameron Ave #BASEMENT, Toronto, ON M6M 1R5', '15 Lower Jarvis St, Toronto, ON'] ['C$1,999+ 1 bd', 'C$2,600+ 2 bds', 'C$1,750+ Studio', 'C$1,900+ 1 bd', 'C$2,750/mo', 'C$1,550+ 1 bd', 'C$3,200/mo', 'C$1,600+ 1 bd', 'C$2,300+ 1 bd', 'C$1,600/mo', 'C$2,000 Studio', 'C$1,950/mo', 'C$2,600/mo', 'C$2,150+ 1 bd', 'C$1,250/mo', 'C$3,980/mo', 'C$2,550/mo', 'C$2,600/mo', 'C$2,100+ 1 bd', 'C$3,000/mo', 'C$2,200 1 bd', 'C$1,650+ 1 bd', 'C$1,600/mo', 'C$1,450/mo', 'C$1,900 1 bd', 'C$1,525 Studio', 'C$2,350 1 bd', 'C$1,980/mo', 'C$2,200/mo', 'C$2,500+ 2 bds', 'C$2,700/mo', 'C$2,100/mo', 'C$1,825 1 bd', 'C$1,800/mo', 'C$2,000/mo', 'C$1,900/mo', 'C$3,000+ 2 bds', 'C$2,980/mo', 'C$1,400/mo', 'C$2,200 1 bd']
```